# MultiThreading in Delphi FMX

Tags: android, multithreading, delphi, firemonkey

I'm trying to iterate though a `TClientDataSet` and refresh a `TLabel` and a `TProgressBar` in Android, but I get this error. How can I fix it?

[image: Error]

This is the execute procedure. is the first time i'm working wuth multithreads in Delphi and i would like to know about that.

I hope you can help me.

```
procedure TThreadCatalogos.Execute;
    var i : Integer;
        AppPath : string;
    begin
        AppPath := System.IOUtils.TPath.GetPublicPath;
       ProgressBar.Min := 0;

       for i := round(ProgressBar.Min) to round(ProgressBar.Max) do begin
           // check if Self(thread) is terminated, if so exit
           if Terminated then
              Exit;
           Position := i;

           {*******************************************}

            Conexion.Open;
            //CLIENTES
            dsClientes.Open;
            //mtClientes.EmptyDataSet;
            dsClientes.First;
            ProgressBar.Max := dsClientes.RecordCount;
            while not dsClientes.Eof do
            begin
              if not mtClientes.Locate('nombre',dsClientes.FieldByName('nombre').AsString,[]) then
              begin
                Synchronize(procedure()
                begin
                  mtClientes.Insert;
                  mtClientes.Fields[0].Value := dsClientes.FieldByName('cliente_id').Asinteger;
                  mtClientes.Fields[1].Value := dsClientes.FieldByName('nombre').AsString;
                  mtClientes.Fields[2].Value := dsClientes.FieldByName('tipo').AsString;
                  mtClientes.Post;
                  mtClientes.SaveToFile(System.IOUtils.TPath.combine(AppPath,'CLIENTES.bin'),sfBinary);
                  lbl.Text := 'Cliente '+floattostr(ProgressBar.Value)+' de '+floattostr(ProgressBar.Max);
                  ProgressBar.Value := ProgressBar.Value + 1;
                 end);
              dsClientes.Next;
            end;
            //mtClientes.SaveToFile(System.IOUtils.TPath.combine(AppPath,'CLIENTES.xml'),sfXML);
            mtClientes.First;

            end); Exit;

          end;
           {************************************************}

       end;
    end;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please visit the [help], particularly [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please provide a [mcve] showing your code that is crashing. And what does this have to do with threading? Your description does not match your title.

Comment: You will be more likely to get help if you provide the code that is producing this error.

Comment: using crystal ball here, you are trying to update the GUI from a thread that is not the main (GUI) thread...

Comment: I wrote the code. Hope you can help me. Thanks

Comment: Ok now that we see some code, I see that you are opening a connection on a separate thread and than do updates on the dataset in the main thread, that won't work. Do all the hard work in your separate thread and sent notifications to the main thread about the progress...

Comment: Also don't touch GUI components (like the progressbar) in the separate thread...

Comment: Seeing that you are new to multithreading, start by reading the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Writing_Multithreaded_Applications_Index) and various resources online...

Comment: @whosrdaddy well, you can touch them, but access to them needs to be synced with the main UI thread

Comment: @FelixHernandez please indicate which line of code is raising the error. The debugger should be telling you that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: yes offcourse, but it would be better if the thread is GUI agnostic, SOLID approach seems to be unknown for many new developers...

Comment: @RemyLebeau how can I sync with the main UI thread?

Comment: @whosrdaddy How can I open the connection and do de updates from the main thread?

Comment: @FelixHernandez look at [`TThread.Synchronize()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.Synchronize) and [`TThread.Queue()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.Queue).  Even something seemingly innocent like reading UI properties such as `ProgressBar.Min/Max` needs to be synced with the UI thread.

Comment: @FelixHernandez: seeing your questions, you clearly did not read the manual... [here is an example](https://blog.delphiedintorni.it/2013/10/una-form-di-attesa-per-operazioni.html) how it should be done (site is in italian, use google translate)

Answer (score 0):

To update a progress bar in a main thread from a child thread one approach is to:

1. Use atomically updateable global variable(s), like a 32 bit integer that you update in the child thread.
2. Use a TTimer event on the form that updates the progress bar based off the values in the global variable(s).

This prevents updating the progress bar too often and lets the thread do a very quick updates to progress.